# XmlListModel windows stuck

Tags: xml, qt, qml

What is the best practice loading xml data to ListView.
I use this code:

```
XmlListModel{
    id:listmodel
    source: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=atom&tags=cats"
    query: "/feed/entry"
    namespaceDeclarations: "declare default element namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom';"
    XmlRole { name:"title"; query: "title/string()" }
    XmlRole { name:"imagesource"; query: "link[@rel=\"enlosure\"]/@href/string()" }
     onCountChanged: console.log("count:", count)
}
BusyIndicator{
    anchors.fill: parent
    running: XmlListModel.status == XmlListModel.Loading
}

ListModel{
    id: fruitModel
    property string language: "en"
    ListElement{
        title: "test"
    }
}

ListView{
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }
    id: listview
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    model:listmodel

    delegate ... ... ..
```

It works well, but while the data loads the window stops responding. I tried to add a busy indicator, but that does not help.
Can I load data from the background and display a busy indicator or something like that?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#using-threaded-list-models-with-workerscript) could help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this did not help, I also tried to use QThread class.
The problem was in the precompiled libraries. (OpenSSL) after 12 hours of compilation with a key -no-openssl problem solved :)